# Does a functor preserving injectives also preserve K-injective complexes?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Let $F:A\to B$ be an exact functor of  Grothendieck abelian categories. If $F$ preserves injective objects, then does the exact functor $F:K(A)\to K(B)$ preserves K-injective complexes?

For example, given an algebraic variety $X/k$, then the inclusion $\mathrm{Qch}(X)\to \mathrm{Mod}(X)$ (from the category of quasi-coherent modules to that of all $O$-modules) preserves injectives. This fact helps to prove that the restriction to $D^+(\mathrm{Qch}(X))$ of the right derived functor $R^+G$ (starting from $D^+(\mathrm{Mod}(X))$) of certain left exact functor $G$ (starting from $\mathrm{Mod}(X)$) is exactly the right derived functor of $G|_{\mathrm{Qch}(X)}$. This leads me to wonder what happens on the unbounded derived categories.

Comment: Being $K$-injective is a property of objects of the homotopy category, not of the derived category.

Comment: Dear @JeremyRickard, Thank you for pointing out this point! I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: *Every* complex over a Grothendieck category is quasi-isomorphic to a $K$-injective complex (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/079I). But for the example in the second paragraph, isn't what you need that $F$ takes $K$-injective complexes to $K$-injective complexes, not just to complexes quasi-isomorphic to $K$-injective complexes?

Comment: Dear @JeremyRickard, You are absolutely right. I am sorry for my mistakes, which reflect my misunderstanding.